# How to setup an Oracle datasource on SSRS 2014

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have two different servers. One is where I have my Oracle 12c DB and the other is where I have my SSRS 14 reporting server. I need to set up an Oracle datasource successfully in SSRS 2014 server but I am not sure what all is needed for it to work.

I installed Oracle 12c client on my DB server and reporting server and have ODAC on my DB server as well. I also set up the environment variables for ORACLE_HOME, PATH and TNS_ADMIN but when I try to do test connection on reporting server it says: "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater."

I am not sure what I could be doing wrong. I am very new to this, can someone tell me what steps are needed from basics to make a successful Oracle Datasource connection?

Comment: I've never set up SSRS, but I do know that since SSRS wants to talk to oracle, that makes the SSRS server  the _client_ server.  So _that_ is where you need to install oracle client, ODAC, etc etc etc.  From you description, it sounds like you put all  the oracle client stuff on the oracle server - where SSRS has no access to it.

Comment: It's been years since I've done it but I do remember it being way more complicated than it should have been. This looks like the way I remember (and apparently the 32/64 bit is still an issue) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dataaccesstechnologies/configure-oracle-data-source-for-sql-server-reporting-services-ssdt-and-report-server